# Equivalent time sampling on microcontrolers

Tags: adc, sampling, high-frequency

I must admit, I don't know too much about analog electronics but I am keen to know if it possible to construct an equivalent time sampler (ETS) using the A/D's on a micro.

I hope this question isn't too vague. Basically my understanding is that ETS is used to sample very high freqeuncy signals and is a trick that is used for digital oscilliscopes.

Wondering if anyone has tried this before or knows of a good reference.

Regards,

Nathan

Answer (score 5):

Equivalent Time Sampling (ETS) is a trick to measure high frequency signals when you can make an assumption about the signal that you are measuring. The assumption is that the signal you are sampling is a repetitive signal (i.e. a sine wave or other "time-constant" signal).

In order to do this in a homebrew fashion you need a means to accurately and repetitively trigger at some fixed location (your trigger point), delay for a variable amount of time and then start and ADC acquisition at fixed intervals.

Triggering can be done with a fast comparator and an accurate reference. If your accurate reference is a filtered or otherwise stable DAC output then you have a nifty (albeit simplistic) software-controlled trigger point. Feed the output of the comparator into a "start timer" capture input on your microcontroller. The idea is to have your microcontroller's timer start counting the instant the comparator fires. When the timer overflows, it starts an ADC capture and stops (until you tell it to watch for the event again).

If you are using a tight loop or interrupt routine (i.e. software) to detect when the timer expires in order to start your ADC capture you may experience some jitter as it will take a variable amount of time to detect that the timer is done. If you can, set the timer interrupt to start the ADC transfer automatically. This is possible on numerous microcontrollers.

If you haven't already guessed, you will be adjusting the timer's starting value in order to give you a variable "pause" before starting the sampling loop. In essence, you'll be "walking across" the repetitive waveform.

Now for the ADC. For simplicity, let's say you will be sampling as fast as you can at all times. (I'll talk about alternatives below.)  What this means is that as soon as the ADC finishes, you will tell it to start again.  Now some microcontrollers are better at this than others; if you can DMA your ADC results and automatically restart, this is your best option. Otherwise you will have ANOTHER source of jitter in your ETS: the delay between an ADC complete interrupt (or polling detecting the completion), storing the sample, and starting another capture.

There is your basic system. pseudocode:

```
volatile int adc_count;

/* assumes you can't use DMA to drive the ADC */
void adc_interrupt(void)
{
    store_value();

    if(--adc_count) {
        start_adc();
    }
}

do {
    int offset;
    offset = 0;               /* offset from trigger to first ADC sample */

    do {
        adc_count = 256;      /* arbitrary, how many samples per trigger */

        load_timer(offset);   /* set timer value */
        arm_timer();          /* timer will now start when the trigger occurs */
    } while(adc_count);

    offset += 10;             /* arbitrary, how much to "move over" each trigger */
} while(offset < 100);        /* arbitrary, how many triggers to use for an ETS capture */
```

Pretty straightforward stuff, but as I mentioned, you need to design the code and select a microcontroller that allows you to have the lowest jitter possible. This means that you want a microcontroller that can be set up such that a timer interrupt can start and ADC capture and that an ADC complete event can DMA results (and restart the ADC). If your microcontroller can't do this then you will have some jitter in your sampling and the captured waveform may look a little "off" as the sample points won't be at evenly spaced intervals.

Now what if you don't want to sample as quickly as possible? You'd want the ADC interrupt to start a second timer that waits the amount of time you want to have between samples, and have that second timer's interrupt start the ADC again.  If you're doing this, you have to be aware that this is yet another source of jitter if you have to use an interrupt routine or polling (i.e. software) to detect and start the peripherals.

In a nutshell, that's ETS.

Comment: ...So is pingswept incorrect that the sampling rate limits your ability to acquire signals?  The way I read this is that you can essentially get as high a resolution as your timer tick supports.  So, for a 20MHz AVR, which traditionally has a 66kHz (off the top of my head) ADC sampling frequency, you could pretend that it had closer to a 20MHz frequency by sampling at 10us, 10.001us, 10.002us etc. after your trigger?  Pretty cool!  I'll have to try this next time.

Comment: I don't believe that pingswept said anything wrong; he said that you'd have trouble accurately reconstructing high frequency signals, and he's right. You need your waveform to "stay still" for quite some time (in computer timeframe) in order to sample it enough times to get a nice picture of it, and even then your uC needs to be pretty good and your ADC as well.  There's a reason good oscilloscopes are expensive. :-)

Comment: Also, you need a Sample & hold that can acquire very fast. Most ADCs readout value is the average of the input over some period of time. You need a circuit that will sample the input value for a *very* short period of time, and then preserve that value long enough for the ADC to convert on it (Generally done with capacitors. There are specialized devices. Google "Sample and Hold").

Comment: Absolutely correct, Fake Name. Every ADC I've used on a microcontroller has had its own sample and hold that effectively decouples the ADC from the input after it's sampling time. If your ADC has a slow S/H (and it probably will) you'll need an external one.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the answer is yes, but the performance would be limited. So far as I know, the highest sampling rates on A/Ds built into microcontrollers is in the 10-100 kHz range. You're also limited by the settling time of the A/D. With a dedicated, high speed, successive-approximation register A/D, you can get above 1 MHz.

For repetitive signals, you could approximate faster signals by using multiple channels, but I suspect that you'd have trouble accurately reconstructing even 1 MHz signals, which is worse than even the cheapest oscilloscope on the market.

Might be fun to try anyway.

I found this description useful: http://www2.tek.com/cmswpt/tidetails.lotr?ct=TI&cs=Application+Note&ci=14295&lc=EN

Answer (score 2):

Been there, done that.

Have ETS working on a 40 MHz microchip dsPIC, which has an ~500 kHz ADC, doing 40 MHz TES with 25 nsec jitter.

The S/H in the ADC is crappy, of course, so the bandwidth of the signal ends up limited by that.  It helps to drive the ADC input with a low-impedance op-amp output, given how the input is basically switched into a capacitor for sampling, and you want that to track rather fast.

The trick to getting this to work was:

1. Trigger off a repeating timer (timer 5, in my case).
2. Set the repeat rate (timer 5 period register) to your real-time sampling rate, i.e. 500 kHz.
3. Have a timebase timer (this was timer 2 in my case) synchronized to your signal somehow (I used a firmware PLL loop, locking to an input capture channel, with great success.)
4. To start an ADC run, copy the value of your timebase timer to the trigger timer, adjusting the value by the necessary delay.  On a microchip, I was doing this in a single instruction: "add delay,[t2],[t5]", where "delay" was calculated so that the trigger timer overflows the first time at the right point in the cycle.  Doing this in a single instruction avoids having to disable interrupts during this operation.
5. Adjust delay value, rinse, repeat.

Your acquisition consists of, say, 80 of those ADC runs, each run collecting samples spaced 2 usec apart.  Each new run starts 25 nsec later in the cycle than the previous run, so 80 runs end up taking a sample at each possible delay, in 25 nsec increments.

Now, this was very microchip-specific; the setup on another MCU may be very different.